# Updating Oracle BLOBs with image files

Tags: oracle10g, blob, fileinputstream

This is what I am trying to do:

1. Read an image from the oracle BLOB
2. Resize it
3. Write the resized image back to the table(update the blob itself).

My table looks like this:

TECHID                         NOT NULL NUMBER(12)

MEDIADATA                      NOT NULL BLOB()

INSERTEDDATE                   NOT NULL DATE

MODIFIEDDATE                   NOT NULL DATE

Steps 1 and 2 work perfectly. The code for step 3 is as follows (this is a PoC type spike solution - not final production):

```
File resized =  get the resized image
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(resized)
PreparedStatement p = db.connection.prepareStatement("update mymediadata set mediadata = ? where TECHID=142") 
if (fis != null)
{
  println("Available: ${fis.available()}"); // this works - shows 117K bytes available.
}
p.setBinaryStream (1, fis, resized?.length()?.intValue())
try
{
  p.executeUpdate()
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace()
}
finally
{
  p.close()
  fis.close()
}
```

When I get to step 3, I get the following error:

SQLException: ORA-01407: cannot update ("OWNER"."MEDIADATA"."MEDIADATA") to NULL

I explicitly checked (in debugger) that the FileInputStream (fis) is not null. I also checked that the `resized?.length()?.intValue()` value is also > 0. So I am struggling to see what I might be doing wrong.

Technology stack:

Groovy GDK 1.7
Java 1.5
Oracle 10g

Running on 32 bit Windows XP.

Comment: This is not related to your problem, but you should be aware that `InputStream.available()` does **not** return the real size of the input stream! It *"Returns an **estimate** of the number of remaining bytes that can be read ... without blocking"* (from the javadocs)

Comment: Thanks for this, however, I only use that call to somehow ensure that my stream object is not null. It serves no other purpose!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I finally managed to resolve this. It turns out it was a dodgy JDBC oracle driver (apparently an earlier version) which was causing the errors.

As soon as I switched to the proper version, the error vanished!